# How to hide input mask on calendar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a specific problem regarding my contact form in HTML5 with hotel-datepicker ([link to hotel-datepicker](https://github.com/benitolopez/hotel-datepicker/)) and intl-tel-input ([link to github](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input))

When I click on input for a date, it shows me what I expect but with two non-UI things:
1. It shows me the earlier date that I put into my input
2. The flag from intl-tel-input is on my calendar

[image: form as it is]
[image: after on click input date]
I will dig into CSS and stuff, but I wanted to ask if there some CSS command that whole section must come first (just to hide flag phone?)
And how can I disable this cookie thing?

This is my HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                <form class="form contact-form" role="form" id="form-div" method="post" action="">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="cf-left-col">
                            <!-- Check In Date -->
                            <div class="form-group required">
                                <input id="input-id" type="text" name="checkindate" placeholder="Check-in  -  Check-Out">
                            </div>

                            <!-- Name -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Name" pattern=".{3,100}">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Mobile phone -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- <input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Mobile phone" pattern=".{3,10}"> -->
                                <input name="mobile" id="mobile" class="mobile input-md round form-control" type="tel">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Email -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Email" pattern=".{5,100}">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Number of adults -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="person" id="inputGuests" class="person input-md round form-control" placeholder="Guests">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Number of children -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="child" id="inpoutChildren" class="person input-md round form-control" placeholder="Children">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cf-right-col">
                            <!-- Message -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" class="input-md round form-control" style="height: 84px;" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Send Button -->
                            <div class="align-right pt-10">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button class="submit_btn btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round" id="submit_btn">Submit Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="cf-left-col">
                            <!-- Inform Tip -->
                            <!-- <div class="form-tip pt-20">
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> All the fields are required
            </div> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="cf-right-col">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="result"></div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
```

In my main.js file is only initialization for tel-mask and hotel-datepicker

Comment: You'll need to post your JS, or preferably a link to a jsFiddle/CodePen/etc that illustrates the behavior with the pre-populated dates. No one will be able to answer definitively based on just the HTML provided. As for the flag showing through, it's likely that it has some CSS placement that, combined with having the same z-index (https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/blob/master/build/css/intlTelInput.css#L25) as the datepicker (https://github.com/benitolopez/hotel-datepicker/blob/master/src/sass/_base.scss#L10) causes it to appear on top.

Comment: @Stevangelista that's it! I've just put z-index:10 on datepicker and it's working. See, we don't need js :) Thanks.